# The app_name of my primary module is replaced by the app_name of dependency module

Tags: android, android-manifest

I download the ZXing from GitHub,then import the folder "android" into my project as a module .It works well as an APP.Then I add the ZXing module as a library for my primary module dependency.It also works well,except the `app_name` and `label` of my primary moudle is replaced by the `app_name` and `label` of the ZXing module.
However,I had modify something in the `Manifest.xml`,as follows:
**the Manifest.xml of the primary module:**

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon,android:label,android:theme">
```

**the Manifest.xml of the ZXIng module:**

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    >
```

After I installed the module in my phone ,the app name is "bar-code scanner",but in the primaray module manifest ,the app_name is "ChargingPile".

Answer (score 1):

It's the **responsability of the library** to either:

- **remove** it's default `resources` such as `app_name` or default colors
  OR
- **prefix** all resources. You can tell Android Studio to report this as warning using the `resourcePrefix` in the library:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    resourcePrefix "goodlibrary_"
}
```

Comment: Now I have resolved the problem.The language of my phone is Chinese,then I removed the `app_name` in the file `res/vaules-ZN-rCN/strings.xml`.Thank you.

Comment: hi @Caelan could you mark my answer as Accepted so? Thanks 